# Oracle not reuse deleted blocks

Tags: oracle, insert, storage, dblink, tablespace

I'm trying to insert data from `PURCHASE_HIST_D` to `PURCHASE_HIST`.

(different schemas in different servers, with DBLINK).

The target table has a lot of deleted data blocks.

This is how I'm checking the segments vs the used blocks:

```
-- result : 199.8743480481207370758056640625 GB
select (AVG_ROW_LEN*NUM_ROWS)/1024/1024/1024 from DBA_TABLES where TABLE_NAME='PURCHASE_HIST'; 

-- result: 250.7939453125 GB
select SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024/1024 from DBA_SEGMENTS where SEGMENT_NAME='PURCHASE_HIST';
```

which means that there are 50 GB of used blocks which can be reuse for the new data.

I'm query the same for the source table:

```
-- result: 21.8079682849347591400146484375
select (AVG_ROW_LEN*NUM_ROWS)/1024/1024/1024 from DBA_TABLES where TABLE_NAME='PURCHASE_HIST_D'; 

-- result: 27.447265625
select SUM(BYTES)/1024/1024/1024 from DBA_SEGMENTS where SEGMENT_NAME='PURCHASE_HIST_D';
```

The source is only 27 GB so It's looks like I dont need to add more space for the tablespace.

This is the free tablespace information:

```
-- result: 1889477 (Used MB)    4923 (Free MB)  1894400 (Total MB)
select
   fs.tablespace_name                          "Tablespace",
   (df.totalspace - fs.freespace)              "Used MB",
   fs.freespace                                "Free MB",
   df.totalspace                               "Total MB",
   round(100 * (fs.freespace / df.totalspace)) "Pct. Free"
from
   (select
      tablespace_name,
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
   from
      dba_data_files
   group by
      tablespace_name
   ) df,
   (select
      tablespace_name,
      round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) FreeSpace
   from
      dba_free_space
   group by
      tablespace_name
   ) fs
WHERE
   DF.TABLESPACE_NAME = FS.TABLESPACE_NAME
   and df.TABLESPACE_NAME = 'TS_DWHDATA';
```

So why when I'm execute the insert (even with NOAPPEND hint) I get an error that there is no enough space in tablesapce?

```
-- examole of the Insert
INSERT
        /*+ monitor NOAPPEND  parallel(64)  statement_queuing */
INTO    DWH.PURCHASE_HIST            
SELECT  *
FROM    DWH_MIG.PURCHASE_HIST_D@DWH_MIG ;
```

The exception:

```
ORA-01653: unable to extend table DWH.PURCHASE_HIST by 8192 in tablespace TS_DWHDATA
```

Comment: What version of Oracle?  I believe many/ most will insert above the high-water mark if you're using parallel query so that multiple threads aren't contending with each other.  But that could be version dependent behavior.

Comment: 11g. Do you have any reference about it?

Comment: Here is one reference https://oracle-randolf.blogspot.com/2011/02/parallel-dml-conventional-non-direct.html  If you do a serial insert, I would expect it to use the blocks below the high water mark.

Comment: This is from the article you've sent:
"As you can see from above output of the test case, direct-path (serial or parallel) loads do not re-use any free space in existing blocks. It will always "append" above the current high-water mark, making the segment grow". It is about serial and parallel loads because of the append. But if I have NOAPPEND hint I excepted that the free blocks will be in use, under the high water mark.

Comment: Direct path inserts do several things, one of which is inserting above the high water mark.  NOAPPEND should force it to do a conventional path insert (depending on the specific version of 11g you have and your configuration) so you'll get full redo generation but I believe there are cases where conventional path parallel loads will write above the HWM.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the free space (using query) from the table but the high watermark is still at the point from where you can not insert data below that.

You need to reclaim that space using the following:

```
alter table your_table enable row movement;

alter table your_table shrink space cascade;
```

Also, You will need to rebuild the indexes of the table after such an operation.

Refer [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm) for reclaiming waste space.

Cheers!!

Comment: But when we using noappend, the purpose is that the database will search the deleted blocks and will insert the new rows there.... if we need to shrink the table - what is the difference between append and noappend??